# default value for RLMObject relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

I have taxonomy structure in database - I'd like to fetch all objects which doesn't have `parent`.

Unfortunetely this query crashes:

`objectsWhere:@"parent == nil"`

In version 0.80 it gave me some sort of log. After update to 0.81 it crashes and doesn't provide me with any log - only mysterious `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

The second issue - might be strongly related to the first one, what value should I set to RLMObject subclass in [defaultPropertyValue](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.81.0/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/defaultPropertyValues) to use method [createInDefaultRealmWithObject](http://realm.io/docs/ios/0.80.0/api/Classes/RLMObject.html#//api/name/createInDefaultRealmWithObject:)

Answer (score 0):

This should now work with the latest release.

From https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md:

"Add support for querying for nil object properties."